# Custom CursorAdapter setText() not updating android

Tags: android, android-cursoradapter, settext

I'm developing an app for android with a ListView using a custom CursorAdapter to retrieve data from a SQLite database. The (cut-down) code for the adapter is supplied below, the problem is that in the `onClick()` method the `pillButton01.setText(Integer.toString(test));` line is not actually updating the button text in the UI, any suggestions? Thanks in advance

```
public class PillTrackerAdapter extends CursorAdapter implements OnClickListener {

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) 
    {
        pillButton01 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.pillButton1); 
        pillButton01.setTag(0);
        pillButton01.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        int tag = (Integer) v.getTag();

        switch(tag) {
            case 0: pillButton01.setText(Integer.toString(test)); 
                    test++;
                break;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That makes sens. pillButton01 is set to the last bound view. (which changes all the time.you need to find out on which listItem you are and act on the view on this item